# Placement algorithm for chord diagram

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

What is a good algorithm for placing nodes on a non-ribbon chord diagram so that nodes are likely to be placed near (strongly) connected nodes?

A non-ribbon chord diagram is a layout for a graph where the nodes are placed radially around a circle.

Examples for non-ribbon chord diagrams are shown [here](http://www.datavizcatalogue.com/methods/non_ribbon_chord_diagram.html).

Comment: Can you explain what "placing nodes on a (non-ribbon) chord diagram" is?

Comment: Is it this? http://www.datavizcatalogue.com/methods/non_ribbon_chord_diagram.html

Comment: @gilleain: Yes, that's an example of a non-ribbon chord diagram.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: I've updated my question accordingly.